# How to make pr assignees a proper environment variable?

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I'm making a github action that edits the README by adding the name of the PR assignees when a pull request is merged. I tried to set a environment variable to use in my python code with the value of `${{github.event.pull_request.assignees}}` however I'm getting the following error when running an exemple PR merge:

```
Error: The template is not valid. 
.github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 32, Col: 22): A sequence was not expected
```

This is my current code:

```yaml
name: READMEUPDATER

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ closed ]
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:

  update:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Edit the README.md
        if: |
            github.event.pull_request.merged == true
            && contains(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, 'workshop')
        run: |
              python ./scripts/updater.py
              git add README.md
              git commit -m "Auto update to README.md"
              git fetch origin master
              git push origin HEAD:master
        env:
          repo: ${{github.event.pull_request.base.repo.name}}
          assignees: ${{github.event.pull_request.assignees}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to solve it, the problem was that it was parsing it as a list not a string to the assignees variables, so I just used this: `${{toJson(github.event.pull_request.assigness)}}`. It serializes the list to a json string. And also the commit part was missing the `git config user.name "xxx"`.